# AutoCompleteTextView does not appear above listview

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-edittext, autocompletetextview

Well I ve been trying this all day but I could not find the error , and I am in a deadend. I have a xml file which I have a listview and of my list I want to have a AutoCompleteTextView which I will use as search bar later.The problem is that in my xml file everything seems to be fine and appears both listview and  AutoCompleteTextView but when i run my app in the emulator prints only the list view. I ve tried to use editText instead of autocoplete but again nothing happened.  here is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".sqlviewpatients" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="AutoCompleteTextView" />



</RelativeLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1" >

</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong? I don t know what else can I do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the error!!! in the .java file I had my class extend List Activity and I had in comment the setContentView(R.layout.something) that was the error, the setContent  should not be a comment!It took me 2 days of to found it so I hope this answer will be helpful to others